# Какие технологии .NET применить?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Какие технологии .NET вы бы применили при создании например клиент серверного чата состоящий и 3 частей (клиент, сервер и подключение к серверной части через веб интерфейс для всевозможных настроек и модерации)?

Comment: для  связи клиента и сервера можно использовать Socket, а почему настройки именно через веб интерфейс?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандартный стек: JQuery/Knockout/Angular (в зависимости от сложности интерфейса и от личных предпочтений), SignalR, ASP.NET MVC (vNext пока сыроват), Redis, EF, MS SQL (или Mongodb, если хочется приключений). Azure в качестве хостинга.

На самом деле очень сильно зависит от мнения и от умения работать с конкретными технологиями. Предлагаю закрыть вопрос как "зависит от мнения" :)